# Member "" not found or not visible after argument dependent lookup line 45

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct

[image: screenshot of my error]i am trying to create e platform which people can contribute in answering questions by sending funds with specific answer to a question: group A or B,
can anyone help me why am i getting this error?

pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract prediction {

```
address private Manager;

string public Question;

string public winnerGroup;

mapping(address => string) userGroup;

mapping(address => uint) payment;

//mapping(address => uint) profitPerUser;


constructor(string memory _Question) {
    Manager == msg.sender;
    Question = _Question;
}


modifier onlyManager() {
    require(msg.sender == Manager);
    _;
}

struct group_A {
    address[] addresses;
    uint totalFund;
    uint userCount;
    uint profitPerUser;
}

struct group_B {
    address[] addresses;
    uint totalFund;
    uint userCount;
    uint profitPerUser;
}







function pickAnswerA() public payable {
    group_A.addresses.push(msg.sender);
    payment[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    group_A.totalFund = msg.value;
    group_A.userCount += 1;
    userGroup[msg.sender] == "A";
}

function pickAnswerB() public payable {
    group_B.addresses.push(msg.sender);
    payment[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    group_B.totalFund += msg.value;
    group_B.userCount += 1;
    userGroup[msg.sender] == "B";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the equality operator (`==`) and the assignment operator (`=`) in several places.

For example:

- `Manager == msg.sender;` should be `Manager = msg.sender;`
- `userGroup[msg.sender] == "A";` should be `userGroup[msg.sender] = "A";`
- `userGroup[msg.sender] == "B";` should be `userGroup[msg.sender] = "B";`

(There might be other things - I haven't actually compiled the code.)

Comment: Thanks.I didn't know that issue,But i am getting the same error again :(

Comment: Okay, I've had a closer look. You have declared the _types_ `group_A` and `group_B`, but you haven't actually declared variables for those types. You need to declare a global variable for each one, and then `.push()` onto those variables. e.g. `group_A A_variable;` and `A_variable.addresses.push(msg_sender);`